# Xpointer: is it possible to select an empty node-set?

Tags: xml, empty-list, xinclude, node-set, xpointer

## Question

I have an `XInclude` that includes a node-set resulting from the specified `xpointer` attribute's expression.

#### *Is it possible to select, with the `xpointer`, an empty node-set, so to not include anything?*

---

## Issue

The reason is that my *xincluded* & *xpointed* node **could** exist and **could NOT** exist; so I'm getting a:

> XInclude error : XPointer evaluation failed

in the case the pointed node does not exist.

---

## Example

The expression is something like:

```
    xmlns(ns=urn:my:namespace)
    xpointer(/ns:element1/*[ns:elementA | ns:elementB])
```

I would like to change the XPointer so that the XInclude does NOT include anything (**without raising the error**) in the case the node is not found.

Something like:

```
    xmlns(ns=urn:my:namespace)
    xpointer(/ns:element1/*[ns:elementA | ns:elementB | NOT_FOUND_NODES ])
```

Is there any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use xi:fallback instruction ?

For example, if you instruct this

```
<xi:include href="somedoc.xml" xpointer="xmlns(ns=urn:my:namespace)xpointer(/ns:element1/*[ns:elementA | ns:elementB])" />
```

and xpointer resource doesn't exists you will get a resource error (as express in xpointer specification). To avoid this, you can use fallback:

```
<xi:include href="somedoc.xml" xpointer="xmlns(ns=urn:my:namespace)xpointer(/ns:element1/*[ns:elementA | ns:elementB])">
   <xi:fallback><NOT_FOUND_NODES/></xi:fallback>
</xi:include>
```

so when xpointer will fall in resource error, fallback will insert  NOT_FOUND_NODES element